# Modifying User data in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement a feature to let super admins modify the data of regular admin account, but I ran into an error of "User security stamp cannot be null." But in the database, there IS the SecurityStamp field filled.

Here are my Admin class which is inherited from the customized ApplicationUser class with no extra fields yet.

```
public abstract class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        //STORED FIELDS
        [Required, StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3), PersonalData]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3), PersonalData]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 6), PersonalData]
        public string NeptunCode { get; set; }

        public int UsernameChangeLimit { get; set; } = 10;

        [PersonalData]
        public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }

        //CALCULATED FIELDS
        public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
```

```
public class Admin : ApplicationUser
    {

    }
```

And here are my AdminController and AdminService methods.

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Modify(int? id, Admin admin)
        {
            if (id != admin.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _adminService.UpdateAdminAsync(admin);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(admin);
        }
```

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateAdminAsync(Admin admin)
        {
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(admin);
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() == 1;
        }
```

And finally, Modify.cshtml

```
<form asp-action="Modify">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control text-center" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control text-center" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control text-center" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control text-center" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check text-center">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="EmailConfirmed" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <label asp-for="NeptunCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NeptunCode" class="form-control text-center" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NeptunCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control text-center" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check text-center">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="PhoneNumberConfirmed" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Back to List</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SecurityStamp is a requierd field . You will have to create a hidden input for Model.SecurityStamp somewhere inside a view form

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="SecurityStamp" value="@Model.SecurityStamp" />
```